# Merge [laravel], [laravel-5], [laravel-5.2], [laravel-4], and [laravel-5.1]

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, tag-alias-request

I saw that there are [five](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/topics) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5/topics) [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5.2/topics) [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-4/topics) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5.1/topics) various versions of Laravel, which is complete overkill given Documentation's version system. Can these be aliased?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that seems like a good idea.

Now that they are aliased, it might be good for someone who knows what they are doing to look for duplication in the [Laravel topics](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/topics?tab=active). In particular, there are several introductory topics that might have significant overlap:

- [Introduction to Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/794/introduction-to-laravel#t=201609300234346444183)
- [Introduction to laravel-5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2246/introduction-to-laravel-5-2#t=20160930023432023057)
- [Introduction to laravel-5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/1987/introduction-to-laravel-5-1#t=201609300234329789741)
- [Jump Start to laravel-5](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/982/jump-start-to-laravel-5#t=201609300237499155601)
- [Introduction to laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2187/introduction-to-laravel-4#t=201609300234337214216)