# Blocking a proposal on documentation

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

Is there a way to block a proposal, essentially launching a counter vote to not add another topic?

Laravel for instance has their main documentation at [/laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/topics), a second one for a [minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5.3/topics) and is now voting to bring in yet another [minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5.4).

The original documentation spans from 5.0 to 5.3. I tried extending some topics to include 5.4. However, my changes were repeatedly denied (all I wanted to change was the version that is noted at the top of each topic for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/7984/eloquent-model#t=201704271208230615258) has 5.0-5.3 when it should be up to 5.4. I digress).

Is there a way to counter vote as it isn't good to spread the documentation so far and wide? Along with that, can you burninate topics or is that just tags?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken all the minor version should be rolled into the main tag and you just use versioning on the examples to show the differences.  I believe CM's have merged theses on other tags.

Comment: Hi @NathanOliver, I'm not too used to the meta side of SO, how would you go about starting that process? And yes you are correct they should be all rolled into one.

Comment: The meta post should start the process.  Might need a mod flag but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: See also the [Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics), [sh](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sh/topics), [shell](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/shell/topics), [command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/command-line/topics) and [command-line-interface](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/command-line-interface) mess.

Comment: @JonEricson This is nowhere near status-completed. The question asks about countering a Docs proposal that happens to be about Laravel, while all that's done so far is merging laravel-version tags into laravel.

Comment: @dorukayhan: Correct. That's why I closed it as a duplicate of the other question which is still open. As far as I know, the immediate support portion of the question _is_ complete.

Answer (score 2):

I already [merged a bunch of Laravel tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335540/merge-laravel-laravel-5-laravel-5-2-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-1). Today, I merged [laravel-5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-5.3) and [laravel-5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) into [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel). (Please go over the topics in [Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/topics) to make sure they are all needed and there aren't duplicate topics.) I also merged in [laravel-4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4.2) under the assumption that it will eventually get enough questions for people to start proposing it.

Did I miss any?

Comment: Nope they look good, however you bring up an interesting point as Laravel 4 is completely different to Laravel 5, I would say 4 should have it's own docs, hopefully there won't be enough questions to warrant it due to being superseded by 5.

Comment: I don't really know the difference between various versions of Laravel. However, Docs is designed to handle divergent versions such as [Python 3.x and 2.x](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/getting-started-with-python-language#t=201704271926532110017&a=versions).